# Unable to display dropdown list for table headers, getting TypeError

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am trying to display the table header list with multiple select, [something like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/SOcUk1?p=preview). In this I am seeing that collection is undefined and predicator is passing, and the distinct itmes data are not displaying.

I getting following error:

```
angular.js:13236 TypeError: displaySetter is not a function

at StTableController.pipe (smart-table.js:163)
at StTableController.sortBy (smart-table.js:124)
at sort (smart-table.js:354)
at m.$eval (angular.js:16820)
at m.$apply (angular.js:16920)
at HTMLTableCellElement.sortClick (smart-table.js:360)
at Rf (angular.js:3398)
at HTMLTableCellElement.Qf.d (angular.js:3386)`
```

Comment: `TypeError: displaySetter is not a function` means that your code expects `displaySetter` to be a function when it is not. It's hard to know what you're doing wrong because you didn't post any code. If you could provide some minimal code that replicates the problem it will greatly help people finding what caused your error.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the st-table attribute is not configured properly. Make sure you have configured the list (that is available in ng-repeat) in st-table. In the below example, customerList is added to the st-table attribute.

```
<table st-table="customerList" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>            
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>            
            <th>state</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"><input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <tr 
            ng-repeat="customer in customerList">
            <td>{{customer.accountNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.address}}</td>            
            <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.state}}</td>           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```